# Using wpdb prepare with a variable, turns it into a big string

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to get data from a custom table in a wordpress database, so I can show different stuff depending on the product visited (I use a variable for that) it's a shop.

So far I have:

```
$sku = $wpdb->esc_like($product->get_sku())."%";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` LIKE "'.$sku.'"');
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
var_dump($result);
```

And I get:

```
array(0) {
}
```

If I put a test sku instead of the variable, it returns results fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` LIKE '%DCAT19%' LIMIT 1";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
echo $sql;
var_dump($result);
```

I get:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` LIKE '%DCAT19%' LIMIT 1 

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#7675 (24) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(17) "DCAT19MDIXHUEFL-L"
    ["fieldcount"]=>
    string(1) "4"
...etc
```

But I need the variable to work, so it can change depending on the product visited.

NOW, if I echo the result from $sql, when using a variable, that is:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` LIKE "'.$sku.'"');
```

It gives a looong string instead of % (!!!):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` LIKE "DCSS20MBJOF01HB{0ff8bf1af1220a9d0556b6de44274e60e96a206d5cac40b1b55605b27fe76b4a}"
```

I have no idea what happens!! I think that's breaking the query, maybe? No idea what to do next.

I've also tried (with variable):

- Double escape the %
- Quote the table and column names
- Calling the variable with %s
- Using sprintf

SAME RESULTS... array in zero and/or looong string instead of a %.

So, if someone could please let me know, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That's not how `wpdb->prepare` works, the whole point of `prepare` is to avoid joining strings and variables together. If you look at your PHP error log you should be seeing warnings that prepare wasn't given enough arguments. If you use prepare correctly, you should not need `esc_like`

Comment: I've also tried: `$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE sku LIKE %s", $sku)` and result is still array (0), would you please elaborate which arguments I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: "It gives a looong string instead of %" - that long string is normal and it's called *placeholder escape string*, and it will be changed back to `%` when `wpdb` sends the parsed query to MySQL. So now that you've corrected the `prepare()` syntax, with that `DCSS20MBJOF01HB` being the `$sku` value, does ``SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` LIKE 'DCSS20MBJOF01HB%' LIMIT 1`` actually return any rows? And by that, I'm saying that if you get an empty array, then it's probably because there really are no rows matching the value of `$sku`.

Comment: Thank you guys. It turns out the `prepare` syntax was wrong, and the data on the table was incomplete, due to a truncated csv import. Fixed both things, and now is working, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `prepare` had bad syntax, and my table was incomplete due to a bad csv import. So, lesson learned, check the manual for syntax, and check (double check!) your tables. Thanks to `Tom` and `Sally` for their comments, they helped me to re-think what was I doing wrong.